# How can I use id as foreign key in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

Suppose I need to create these 2 models.1.Make a Product Model with fields Name, Description, Price 2. Make a Stock model with ProductID(foreignkey Reference), Name, Description, Price, Quantity..
Now my question is this how can I take id as foreign key from Product to Stock model?

Comment: Is it possible to ask a *question*. Just providing some skeleton of a model is *not* a question. Exactly *what* problem do you aim to solve, why do you think using `id` as ` ForeignKey` is a solution?

Comment: suppose I need to create these 2 models.1.Make a Product Model with fields Name, Description, Price
2. Make a Stock model with ProductID(foreignkey Reference), Name, Description, Price, Quantity...Now my question is this how can I take id as foreign key from Product to Stock model?

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the `ForeignKey` as [**`primary_key=True`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#primary-key):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)

class Stock(models.Model):
    product = models.OneToOneField(
        Product,
        primary_key=True,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=4096)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

Since this is a primary key, this is a unique field. So you can *not* make two or more `Stock` objects that refer to the *same* `Product`.

Comment: Not working .SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
<class 'Product_Detials.admin.StockAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[0]' refers to 'product ', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'StockAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'Product_Detials.Stock'.

WARNINGS:
Product_Detials.Stock.product: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True on a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a OneToOneField.HINT: ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField.

Comment: @mehedi1501: but it looks the problem is here with the `ModelAdmin`, not with the `Model` itself?

Comment: #code for admin.py
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Product,Stock

class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','name', 'description')
admin.site.register(Product, ProductAdmin)

class StockAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('product','name', 'description','price','quantity')
admin.site.register(Stock, StockAdmin)

Comment: Can you please tell me where's the problem?It'll be so much helpful for me